# How to get min and max date smaller equal to today mysql

Tags: mysql

I need help with mysql statement.
I have 2 tables, one holds events details the other the event dates.

I need to display all events dates that end today or later.

I have an event that have these dates:
29/03/2016
30/03/2016
31/03/2016

I tried this query:

```
SELECT a.event_id, event_name, event_location, event_desc,
MIN(a.event_date) AS from_date, MAX(a.event_date) AS to_date
FROM event_time a
LEFT JOIN event_time b
ON b.event_id = a.event_id
JOIN events c
ON a.event_id = c.event_id
WHERE b.event_date <= NOW()
GROUP BY a.event_id
```

But in the from_date field I get only 31/03/2016.

Can anyone please help on building the correct statement for what I need?

Thank you

Comment: Why are you using `LEFT JOIN event_time b`. I mean joining with same table

Answer (score 2):

Well you question lack's a bit information, so if I understood you correctly, you don't need to join twice to event_times:

```
SELECT a.event_id, event_name, event_location, event_desc,
       MIN(a.event_date) AS from_date, MAX(a.event_date) AS to_date
FROM event_time a
JOIN events c
 ON a.event_id = c.event_id
WHERE a.event_date >= NOW()
GROUP BY a.event_id
```

I've changed your where clause to

```
a.event_date >= NOW()
```

Since you said you wan't dates bigger or equal to today's date, but now I'm looking in your topic and I see you wrote the opposite, so if you wan't smaller, turn it around.

Also, in general, you are `LEFT JOINING` to event_time b, and you have in your where clause:

```
WHERE b.event_date <= NOW()
```

This automatically turns the join into an inner join, filters on the `right` table should be only in the `ON` clause. In your case:

```
LEFT JOIN event_time b
 ON b.event_id = a.event_id AND
    b.event_date <= NOW()
```

Comment: Ok, sorry for the confustion, working on a few sites together, my thoughts are a mess.
Let me explain a bit more:
I need to display events that ends today or in the future.
I need to display their Start Date to End date.

My event has these dates:
29/03/2016, 30/03/2016, 31/03/2016, 01/04/2016 (tomorrow)
e.g. for my event I need to display:
Event Dates: 29/03/2016 to 01/04/2016

With sagi's statement the to_date I get is 31/03/2016 and not 01/04/2016 because of the WHERE statement which is what I'm struggling with.

Comment: @SigalZahavi Then remove the WHERE , but I don't understand, you said you want only the dates that happend before today, why do you want to get 1/4 ?

Comment: sagi, I need all the events that end today or after today. If I don't have a WHERE I will get all the events I have in the database, even if they already finished, e.g. their end date is yesterday, last week, last month or last year. Hope you understand what I'm trying to say.
I didn't say I want only the dates that happened before today I said: "I need to display events that ends today or in the future"